# How do I pass a specific element of 2D List to the ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter project Where I got a recipes data.

**How do I get the data:**

```
Future<dynamic> getRecipeData(String recipeID) async {
    try {
      CollectionReference users =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes');
      final snapshot = await users.doc(recipeID).get();
      final data = snapshot.data();
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Error fetching user';
    }
  }
```

The `data` returns the data in the following format `[{recipeName: Aalo Sabzi, recipeDescription: Aalo Sabzi Description, recipeTime: 5 min, recipeIngrediants: [Ingrediants 01, Ingrediants 02, Ingrediants 03], recipeRating: 0, recipeURL: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/f5E1TOeLKrk/maxresdefault.jpg}]`

Previously When I was making a UI I use hard coded data where I used different Lists for recipeName,recipeDescription, recipeTime etc.
Like this:

```
final List recipesName = [
    'Aalo Sabzi',
    'Paalak Sabzi',
    'Chicken Haandi',
    'Fish Fry',
    'Paneer Tikka',
    'Rajma Chawal',
  ];
  final List recipesTime = [
    '5 min',
    '15 min',
    '25 min',
    '30 min',
    '45 min',
    '20 min',
  ];
  final List recipesRating = ['5', '4.8', '3.75', '4.5', '5', '4.5'];
  final List recipesURL = [
    'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/f5E1TOeLKrk/maxresdefault.jpg',
    'https://i0.wp.com/www.bharatzkitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Aloo-PALAK.jpg?fit=640%2C361&ssl=1',
    'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/O-e6kFDfKuc/maxresdefault.jpg',
    'https://geekrobocook.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/6.-Paneer-Tikka-1200x900.jpg',
    'https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/60017797.cms?width=1200&height=900',
    'https://www.secondrecipe.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/rajma-chawal-1.jpg',
  ];
```

Then I pass this hard coded data to my `recipeCard` class where it shows the data in the card format

```
ListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
  itemCount: recipesName.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return RecipeCard(
      isAdmin: true,
      title: recipesName[index],
      cookTime: recipesTime[index],
      rating: recipesRating[index],
      thumbnailUrl: recipesURL[index],
    );
  },
),
```

This is how I am getting the data from firestore database into my ViewRecipes Class

```
List<List> recipes = [];
  Future<void> getUserData() async {
    int col = (await RecipeModel().getRecipeCount()) - 1;
    int recipeID = 101;
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++, recipeID++) {
      recipes.add([await RecipeModel().getRecipeData(recipeID.toString())]);
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Now what I want is that when I got the recipe data in this format `[{recipeName: Aalo Sabzi, recipeDescription: Aalo Sabzi Description, recipeTime: 5 min, recipeIngrediants: [Ingrediants 01, Ingrediants 02, Ingrediants 03], recipeRating: 0, recipeURL: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/f5E1TOeLKrk/maxresdefault.jpg}]` **How can I pass the the all the data
from the above list recipe List: `recipeName` to the `title`, `recipeTime` to `cookTime` etc.**

Comment: I don't completely understand your question
Why are you using a list of a list? You can simply get a list of `RecipeModel` and use that in your list

Comment: Actually I am trying to make 2D List where row 1 will have recipeName, recipeDescription etc and similarly I have many other rows of different recipe data

Comment: You can create a model class `Recipe` and then get a list of `Recipe` objects from the backend. Then provide the `Recipe` object to your list item using the index. You don't need a list of list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a model class Recipe and then get a list of Recipe objects from the databse i.e Firetore Database, then provide the Recipe object to your list item using the index.